# How to Extract Relevant Data from cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very bad Excel sheet which I try to fix.

Instead of getting separated columns, I got lines which I separated into different columns using ''text to columns.''

Now I have a problem, because one of the columns has different length and I can't use text to columns in order to separate the data I need.

Here you can see the data I need to extract and the different locations in has:

[image: here you can see the data I need to extract and the different locations in has]

This is how my column looks like, I need the dates like the one that marked in red, but as you can see, down in the list, the location of the dates is different, so I can't use the ''text to columns''
how can I solve it

Comment: The attached screen shot is original data or the result,,if not original please [Edit] your question and add sample data for better understanding.

Comment: This can be solved using **Text to Column**, but first confirm that Screen Shot data is original or what!

Comment: It sounds like you are using the "Fixed width" option of Text to Columns. You should probably use the "Delimited" option and specify `;` and `_` as the delimiters. If you don't want the delimiters to be removed, you will need to replace them after the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

1. Select Column- go to **Data**- **Text to Columns**- Select **Delimited**- check **Other** and enter **;**- Finish
2. Move Column C to Column D- select Column B- go to **Data**- **Text to Columns**- Select **Delimited**- check **Other** and enter **_**- Finish
   [image]